# How can i call an Async method from a filter attribute in ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, async-await, actionfilterattribute

I am attempting to make an `async/await` request from my custom `FilterAttribute` shown bellow. The problem i am having is that, this is `MVC5` and there are no asynchronous base class for filter attributes that i am aware of, so I am having to use `Task` to achieve the same result. I do know using `Task` may affect the perfomance but i can think of any other way to get around this.

The method i wish to make `async/await` call with is `_authService.IsUserSessionValid`

I need to make an call to an asynchronous method which accesses the database and returns a value. I am unable to do that which is why i wrapped the call in a `Task` I am realising that the `OnActionExecuting` is being called twice, also the `filterContext.Result` does not redirect the user to the Action `"SignOut"` as I thought it would. How do i fix this ?

```
public class SingleSessionValidationFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            var _authService = (IAuthService)DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof(IAuthService));
            var _formsAuthenticationHelper = (IFormsAuthenticationHelper)DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof(IFormsAuthenticationHelper));

            var currentUserId = _formsAuthenticationHelper.GetLoggedInUserId();
            var currentCookieId = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["CookieKey"]?.Value;
            var task = Task.Run(
                async () => _authService.IsUserSessionValid(new UserSessionValidityCheckerViewModel()
                {
                    CookieId = currentCookieId,
                    UserId = currentUserId
                }));

            task.Wait();

            if (task.Result.IsCompleted)
            {
                var value = task.Result.Result;
                if (!value)
                {
                    filterContext.Result = new System.Web.Mvc.RedirectToRouteResult(
                        new RouteValueDictionary
                        {
                            {"action", "SignOut"},
                            {"controller", "Account"}
                        });
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Nothing is being awaited inside your async lambda.

Comment: Is this `IsUserSessionValid` really async or it's just you who wrap it in `Task.Run`? What's the story behind this?

Comment: @WiktorZychla I am creating a way to track user session, the project is quite old and doesnt use IdentityServer to authenticate. So for single session, when user is signs into the account (instance 1), a cookie is created and stored in the in the HttpContext Cookie, as well as a DB against the user id, when the same user signs on somewhere else (instance 2), they're allowed to log in but the database is updated with the new cookie.. so if the user tries to use the previous instance, like click a button, the filter attribute checks on every action if the cookie is valid, and if not, signs out

Comment: @WiktorZychla and yes, IsUserSession is an async awaitable Task

Comment: you dont need the word async within your `Task.Run();` There is no awaitable task so it will run synchronously anyway.

Comment: There is no way to have an async call in a filter without risking the deadlock. What you can do is you can walkaround this issue. An [example approach here](https://evandontje.com/2017/08/15/solutions-for-async-await-in-mvc-action-filters/).

Comment: What is `IAuthService`? What is the signature of `IsUserSessionValid` and what is the definition of its result type?

Answer (score -1):

If _authService.IsUserSessionValid returns a `Task<bool>` then you can write

```
await task; // awaits the task, thus making it asynchronous
```

instead of

```
task.Wait(); // this will block further execution until the task completes
```

after that you can check for result and redirect.